# Azure Active Directory to authenticate multiple applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have a situation which I have not been able to find examples of online. I have three country specific applications E, F and G which share to common applications A and B.

I am looking to have each of the country applications, E, F and G to connect to applications A and B through SSO using Azure AD as the IDP (SAML 2.0). Each of the application E, F & G have individual users who shouldn't log into the other application but the users should be able to authenticate on A and B

Is there anyone who has implemented such a setting willing to share their experience?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with Azure AD conditional access?

I would add an IDP for each country application e.g. ADFS and then connect the application to the local ADFS and federate ADFS with Azure AD.

That way users can only login to their local AD.

Comment: Let me investigate your suggestion, I'll get back to you

Comment: From the reading I've done and examples I've gone through, ADFS seems to be running on Windows server? The three country applications run online on linux VMs so no chance of running the Relying Party Trust Wizard

Comment: When I said an IDP, it doesn't have to be ADFS. It could be identityserver or IdaaS e.g. Auth0, Okta etc.